Why is the amplitude of the output voltage affected by the resistance during resonance when LC is connected in parallel with a resistor in series
The following picture is the circuit I simulated.

My question is, through theoretical calculations, the resonant frequency of this circuit F = 1 / (2 * pi * sqrt(LC)), so in my circuit, F = 0.15915494309189533576888376337251， It should be unrelated to resistor R, but during simulation, I found that when resistor R = 100 and R = 100k, the resonant frequency changed and the output amplitude also decreased. May I ask what is going on?
Here are my simulation parameters.



Here are my simulation results.
when R1 = 1, it seems right.


when R1 = 100, It's starting to go wrong


when R1 = 100k, It's Very incorrect



Do an AC spectrum analysis so that any sharpening of the Q factor doesn't result in you missing the increasingly harder-to-hit resonant point when using an oscillator.

You are most likely having issues with the Maximum Time Step size that is specified in the .tran card. Setting it to 10m will probably cure the issues with the simulation.
